# Best way to move all data on a sheet over by a few columns? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the best way to move all the data on a sheet over by 5 columns. I dont want to insert new cells because I want the cell references to stay the same for certain cells. There will always be data (with some blank cells) from row 4 to 486, but every week there will be new data added to the first 5 columns so the numbers of columns with data will always be increasing. I have tried the following:

1.
Range("A:E").EntireColumn.Insert

which as the stated, didnt work because i need the cell references to stay the same.

2.

```
Range("A4:CB486").Select 'CB486 just being some arbitrary cell that wont be filled for a while, ideally this would be a changing reference to whatever is the last column with data
Selection.Copy

Cells.Clear
Range("F4:CG486").PasteSpecial
```

this doesnt work and I am not sure why. Does anyone have a more effective/efficient method to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless I've missed something, the `cell references` you refer to are the Addresses of cells? If that's the case, moving the cells will always mean that data ends up at a different cell address, a different place in the sheet.

Comment: Why do you need the cells to stay the same, is it because there are other formulas that depend on them? If so I think you should make those formulas the target of your question - "what can I do to make this formula work no matter how many columns are added to the sheet?"

Comment: Yes sorry exactly, cells on different sheet rely on this data, but i want the cells on the other sheet to always look at the same cell (so every week i will upload a new table being the first 5 columns) so i always want them to look at the newest table of data regardless of theold data shifting places

Comment: In that case, use `INDIRECT` formulas rather than normal cell references, and then they won't move when you insert new columns